# What exactly is a torsion line bundle?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

I am currently studying bigness of divisors, and its relationship between its numerical class and Kodaira dimension (using the aide of Lazarsfeld's Positivity in Algebraic Geometry I). I understand that if $D$ is numerically trivial, then its Kodaira dimension, $kod(D)$, is either $-\infty$ or $0$, and in particular, $Kod(D)=0 \Longleftrightarrow [D]$ is a torsion line bundle. Can someone please explain to me what exactly makes a line bundle torsion?

Comment: Presumably it means that some power of $D$ is trivial.

Comment: Torsion in the Picard group.